# Recursion execution steps in python

Tags: python, recursion, linked-list, reverse

I've been puking trying to understand reversing a linked list with incursion:

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None # Head of list
 
    # Method to reverse the list
    def reverse(self, head):
 
        # If head is empty or has reached the list end
        if head is None or head.next is None:
            return head
 
        # Reverse the rest list
        rest = self.reverse(head.next)
 
        # Put first element at the end
        head.next.next = head
        head.next = None
 
        # Fix the header pointer
        return rest
```

So I start with a simple recursion like

```py
def sum(x):
    if x == 1:
        print("at x = ", x, "k = ", 2.5)
        return 2.5
    else:
        k = x * sum(x-1)
        k +=1.5
        print("with x =", x, "we have k =",k)
        return k
sum(6)
```

I thought the steps will begin from 6 downwards:

```
k = 6 * 5 + 1.5
k = ((6 * 5) + 1.5) * 4 + 1.5)
k = ((6 * 5) + 1.5) * 4 + 1.5) * 3 + 1.5
k = ((6 * 5) + 1.5) * 4 + 1.5) * 3 + 1.5) * 2 + 1.5
k = ((6 * 5) + 1.5) * 4 + 1.5) * 3 + 1.5) * 2 + 1.5) * 2.5
```

But in fact it's the other way around:

```
at x =  1 k =  2.5
with x = 2 we have k = 6.5
with x = 3 we have k = 21.0
with x = 4 we have k = 85.5
with x = 5 we have k = 429.0
with x = 6 we have k = 2575.5
2575.5
```

So if that's how recursion works, coming back to the reversing linked-list with recursion, supposing we have a linked list:
1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 --> 6 --> None.

I understand that when:

```
* head.next = 6 -> rest = self.reverse(6) -> head.next (6.next) is None then return 5.
* head.next.next (6.next.next) = 5.
* head.next (5.next) = None
So we have 6 --> 5 --> None. Then will work all the way back to 1 --> None?
```

Comment: that's because your print statement is _after_ the recursive call to `sum(x - 1)`, so it shows the order as it comes back from the deepest level and up. It would be easier to see the calling order if you put a print statement just after `def sum(x)`. As an aside, it's never great form to override a builtin. You could use `sum_` instead.

Comment: Is `sum(6)` indented correctly?  In your code snippet it's within function body, so it might mess everything up.

Comment: @KlasŠ. My bad, I've fixed it. Sum(6) is just to run the function.

Comment: @PierreD. Thank you for pointing out. I'm new to posting content to stackoverflow so I'm still learning. 
And as for the print function, I mean it's just to show the code from the deepest level up like from bottom to top. Not from top to bottom. What I'm asking is is that the way recursion works? It goes to the deepest level and works its way back outside?

Comment: I don't understand your question: "is that the way recursion works?" There is no magic treatment for a recursive function. Just like a normal function, the code is executed one step at a time. When it hits a call to itself, it doesn't do anything different than it would if calling a different function: the called function executes on a new stack frame, and when it returns, the code pointer is back to where we left, and with the variables in our frame. You could use a good debugger and see the stack, observe the variables at each level, etc.

Comment: In your recursive function, you do start from x but you call sum(x - 1) before you print your output and so on until x is equal 1, then you continue to your print function and print '1' first, and then return to the previous call and print the second output, and so on.